# Extremely Long Difficult Number Sequence

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

(2 7 4 4 5 7),
(?),
(2 1 3 2 1 7 1 4 1 5),
(2 2 4 1 1 3 1 7 1 4 1 5),

I can't find any links between these numbers, anyone could help me solve it?

Comment: Vandalism is not the proper way to delete your post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232

Comment: Sorry about the vandalism..but I can’t delete this question now...could you help me with that? @Glorfindel

Comment: Have you read the FAQ, especially the "If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?" part?

Comment: I got it...okay.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer

> 12272415

Reasoning

> This is an inventory of the number of occurrences of each digit, in order of first appearance. For instance, from 2132171415, there are two 2's, four 1's, one 3, (skip the 2 and 1, already seen), one 7, (skip 1), one 4, (skip 1) and one 5.